# PHP Redirect user and save previous URL in browser's history

Tags: php, redirect, header, browser-history

This got me quite confused. Let me say a user visits a folder **A**, but, let's say, because of some reason he is being redirected to a folder **B**. The problem is that a browser does not log the location **A** into its history.

***url/A*** redirects to a little different location ***url/B***

After user clicks on "history back button", he does not reach the previous ***url/A*** location. It's kinda omitted, I'd say.

I've tried these 2 methods for the redirect. And it seems they are not saving the current URL into the browser's history.

```
header("Refresh:0; url=$url_b");
header('Location: '.$url_b);
```

Comment: Why should A _be_ in the history in the first place? The response to that request was nothing my browser could "display" in any way, and it was told right away that it should go look elsewhere - so why would I want to "return" there to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe let's say a user didn't match some condition and he was redirected. Next time the user might match the condition and gonna stay or be redirected somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm still questioning the reason, but you maybe able to use javascript on page **A** for redirection. In this way we are able to get back to where we were on back click.

So here we have a js script that only runs if a php condition is true:

```php
<?php
if (condition) { ?>
    <script>
        window.location.href = "http://example.com/B";
    </script>
<? }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL_A could have typing errors. The php-script returns a message "Unknown URL" using URL_B. It would be usefull that the user can check and correct the URL_A he introduced. It's impossible that URL_B can solve all typing errors, thus returning to URL_A is needed.
The proposed solution can not work because it uses a fixed URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).